# Create multiple docker containers by running same docker-compose config

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to start a job on a remote server:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  solution-app:
    container_name: solution_new_name_v3
    build: .
```

I ran the following command to deploy the container:

`docker-compose -H "ssh://..." up -d --build`

This works great, now I wanted to start another job in parallel using the same docker compose file, but with some minor changes in the source code. So I changed the `container_name` in the compose config and assumed that it should start a new container. However, instead of starting a new container my previous container was stopped and replaced with a new one with this new name.

So my question is: how can I start few containers running in parallel using same docker-compose config?

Comment: Do you know that you can define and run 2 containers in one compose file? Will it be good for your needs?

Comment: docker compose runs an application (consisting of services, volumes, etc.) based on the name of the file - so changing the contents of the file changes the definition of the application. It sounds like you want to run another application in parallel? So just copy the compose file to a new name and bring that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure out the way:
so Docker compose maps all services based on the project name, which is by default a directory name. To override the project name one can use:
[docker-compose -p NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/)

Alternatively one can set [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) env variable